# Why is listview that uses loaders empty with fts3 table on Android?

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, listview

Basically my listview that uses a CursorLoader to load data was displaying fine with my normal table, but once I converted my table to fts3 (to use MATCH for searching) it stopped displaying data.

**Table declaration:**

```
 public static final String NOTES_SCHEMA="CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+" USING fts3("+
            "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY"+COMMA+NOTE_TITLE+" TEXT"+COMMA+NOTE_TEXT+" TEXT"+COMMA+TRASH_STATUS+" INTEGER DEFAULT 0"+COMMA+TIME+" INTEGER"+");";
```

**onCreateCursorLoader:**

```
case LOADER_NOTELIST_ID:
           String[] projection = new String[]{NotesModel.NotesTable._ID, NotesModel.NotesTable.NOTE_TITLE, NotesModel.NotesTable.NOTE_TEXT,NotesModel.NotesTable.TIME,NotesModel.NotesTable.TRASH_STATUS};
            String sortOrder = NotesModel.NotesTable.TIME+ " DESC";
            String where = NotesModel.NotesTable.TRASH_STATUS+"=0";
            CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(getApplicationContext().getApplicationContext(), uri, projection, where, null , sortOrder
            );

            return cursorLoader;
```

I also noticed when I removed the where argument, it worked (but i need that argument).

**Content Provider:**

```
 public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {

    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    Cursor cursor;

    switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case NOTES_LIST://display the whole list, for main activity
            qb.setTables(NotesModel.NotesTable.TABLE_NAME);//set table to be queried
           break;

        case NOTES_ITEM:
            qb.setTables(NotesModel.NotesTable.TABLE_NAME);
            qb.appendWhere(NotesModel.NotesTable._ID + " = "+ uri.getLastPathSegment());
            break;

        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid URI: " + uri);
    }

    cursor = qb.query(db,projection,selection,selectionArgs,null,null,sortOrder);
    cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);//observer for loader
    return cursor;
}
```

Any comments or solutions would highly be appreciated.

Comment: did you try to execute sqlite3 app and test your query "by hand"?

Answer (score 1):

After much research I come to the conclusion that the fts3 table just can't support **CursorLoader()** or a **query()** due to the parameters.

Overall, fts3 by default doesn't support parenthesis and I discovered that the selection parameter of the two methods above is within parenthesis automatically when executed. For that reason my listview was empty, and that's why once the where clause was removed it was once again working. I however need that selection parameter and at the end of the day I don't have a actual solution to fixing this problem after searching the internet.